Migration from uuv_thruster to gz-sim thruster plugin
I'm facing some difficulties in migrating some code from gazebo-classic to gz-sim.
I have an unmanned surface vehicle equipped with four thrusters that receive the target propeller speed as control input.
The original project was written on ROS Kinetic/gazebo-classic, this one will be written on
ROS2 Humble/gz-garden.
In the first project the thrusters were configured using "libuuv_thruster_ros_plugin" and the settings were the following:
            <plugin name="t${thruster_id}_thruster_model" filename="libuuv_thruster_ros_plugin.so">
        <!-- Name of the thruster link -->
        <linkName>t${thruster_id}_frame</linkName>

            <!-- Name of the joint between thruster and vehicle base link -->
            <jointName>t${thruster_id}_joint</jointName>
            
            <!-- Make the thruster aware of its id -->
            <thrusterID>${thruster_id}</thrusterID>

            <!-- Gain of the input command signal -->
            <gain>1</gain>

            <!-- Minimum and maximum thrust force output allowed -->
            <!-- 9.2 Kgf -> 90 N -->
            <thrustMin>-90</thrustMin>
            <thrustMax>90</thrustMax>
            
            <!--
            Input limit value for the input signal for thruster unit
            7200 RPM -> 750 rad/s maybe pwm [0;100] is better
            -->
            <clampMin>-750</clampMin>
            <clampMax>750</clampMax>

            <!--
            Value from 0 to 1 to set the efficiency of the output thrust force
            Default value is 1.0
            -->
            <thrust_efficiency>1</thrust_efficiency>

            <!--
            Value from 0 to 1 to set the efficiency of the propeller as a factor
            to be multiplied to the current value of the state variable at each
            iteration.
            Default value is 1.0
            -->
            <propeller_efficiency>1</propeller_efficiency>

            <dynamics>
                <type>ZeroOrder</type>
            </dynamics>

            <conversion>
                <type>Basic</type>
                <rotorConstant>0.00016</rotorConstant>
            </conversion>
         </plugin>

In my implementation the generated force (echoed with gz-topic) is correct, but the propellers speed is insanely higher when compared to the original one! Am I configuring the thrusters plugin correctly? I've tried to follow the comments on the plugin repo:
        <plugin filename="gz-sim-thruster-system" name="gz::sim::systems::Thruster">
          <namespace>ares2</namespace>
          <topicName>thrust_topic</topicName>
          <joint_name>t${thruster_id}_joint</joint_name>
          <fluid_density>1000</fluid_density>
          <propeller_diameter>0.09</propeller_diameter>
          <thrust_coefficient>0.00016</thrust_coefficient>
          <max_thrust_cmd>750</max_thrust_cmd>
          <min_thrust_cmd>-750</min_thrust_cmd>
          <use_angvel_cmd>1</use_angvel_cmd>
          <velocity_control>1</velocity_control>
        </plugin>

Thanks in advance!
